# Celery max concurrency

Tags: python, celery, python-multithreading, celery-task

I have a doubt, leet's see:

My maximum concurrency is 8.

I have one big task with a lot of threads (max 150 controlled by Sempahore), are these threads limited by the worker concurrency??

I thought the maximum concurrency for celery worker would be the number of tasks in parallel, not the threads created inside the task.

Do you know guys?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you simply write a small test to find out? :)

Comment: finally, I did, and yes, threads are counting as concurrency for Celery.